# Error :Cannot find symbol

Tags: java, android

Hello i am learning how to develop android apps but i have some problem while compiling.

the code :

```
   public void  onButtonClick(view v) {
    Edittext r1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    Edittext r2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    TextView t  = (Textview)findViewById(R.id.textView);
     int num1 = integer.parseint(r1.gettext().tostring);
     int num2 = integer.parseint(r2.gettext().tostring);
     int sum = num1+num2;
    t.setText(integer.tostring(sum));

}
```

And the imports are :

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

[image]

Comment: just hover mouse cursor over `EditText` and press `ALT + ENTER` and you see `import`

Comment: press alt+enter on red fields and import these classes

Comment: should i create class of EditText and Testview because i see on google that the view contains Edittext , testview , checkbox..

Answer (score 1):

Your casing is wrong for all of those..

```
view -> View
Edittext -> EditText
Textview -> TextView
integer -> Integer
gettext -> getText
```

In most cases, you should follow these rules

Classes and interfaces have the first letter of each word capitalized. ex: `TextView`, `EditText`

Methods and variables should be camelcased. (first letter lowercase, first letter of each subsequent word uppercase) ex: `getText()`, `doTheThing()`

I recommend you read this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html